# Sum of convergent geometric series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

The sum is

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{4^n}$$

$R=\frac{1}{4}<1$ which means it's convergent, so to find the sum we use the Geometric test which looks like 
$$\frac{a}{1-r}$$
$$\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{1}{\frac{3}{4}}=\frac{4}{3}$$ but the book is telling me it's $\frac{4}{5}$, the sum already starts a zero so I can't change that and I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: The $x^n$ in the geometric series should be $\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^n$, which leads to the formula $\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{4}}$.

Comment: The terms here alternate in sign. You found the sum of the series when all the terms are positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $r=-\frac{1}{4}$, notice, that consecutive terms have different signs because of $(-1)^n$. Consequently $S=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{1}{\frac{5}{4}}=\frac{4}{5}$